# Network redirect issues

Tags: multisite

I've searched WP Dev Stackexchange for this, but none of the questions posted seems to have a solution for this.

I've created a network in WP (4.8). I've added the following settings to w-config.php:

```
define( 'WP_ALLOW_MULTISITE', true );
define('MULTISITE', true);
define('SUBDOMAIN_INSTALL', false);
define('DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE', $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']);
define('PATH_CURRENT_SITE', '/');
define('SITE_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1);
define('BLOG_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1);
define('ADMIN_COOKIE_PATH', '/');
define('COOKIE_DOMAIN', '');
define('COOKIEPATH', '');
define('SITECOOKIEPATH', '');
```

And this to the .htacess-file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$ $1wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(.*\.php)$ $2 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

All plugins and the theme are activated on network level.
When I try to enter the dashboard of the original site (located in "/") everything is fine, the theme and plugins activated in the network are working as expected.
When I try to visit either of the two other sites created in the network the theme is not set (just the standard WP theme). The site prefix breaks all links to plugins and theme. When I try to login to the dashboard I get a 302 and "Too many redirects".

Answer (score 0):

Oh, thess lines are not supposed to be present in the htaccess-file if using subdomains:

```
# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$ $1wp-admin/ [R=301,L]
```